# タイムラインに簡単にアクセスできるようにリンクを設置してもいい？

Tags: 機能の要求

このサイトにはタイムラインという機能があります。タイムラインとは、投票された時間、コメントの付いた時間、編集された時間などを見るための機能です。

タイムラインを見る方法は

1. URLにあるタイトルの部分を`timeline`にする
   (短縮URLならユーザーのID?の部分を消す)
2. `questions`を`posts`にする
   (短縮URLなら`q`もしくは`a`の部分を`posts`にする)

という手順を踏む必要があります。

---

しかし、これだと少し手間がかかる気がします。さらに、タイムラインという機能があるというのに気が付きにくいと思います(私はつい最近知りました)。
そこで、簡単にアクセスできるようリンクを設置すると良いと思います。タイムラインという機能を知るきっかけにもなります。

Comment: 重複候補: [タイムラインへのリンクを表示して欲しい](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1590/15185)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Add a link to the timeline of a post - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180594/286934)

これですね。[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) になってるのでそのうち実装されるかもしれませんが、ひとまずは UserScript を使ってはいかがでしょうか。

[View Post Timeline - Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/a/4150/34348)